# How do I automatically direct the cursor in keyboard shortcuts for sublime text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I work a lot with ruby on rails so naturally I code a lot in erb. Typing <%= %> is always a pain so I wrote a keyboard shortcut script for in Key Bindings. Here is my code:

`{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+e"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "<%= %>"}}`

This is okay however this simply creates <%= %> and the cursor ends up after the > sign. How do I make it so that it creates <%= %> and the cursor ends up in between <%= and %> so I can start typing right away?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+e"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "<%="$0"%>"}}
```

As per the documentation provided here placing the $0 would make the cursor move to that position. I also suggest you create an autocomplete mentioned here in this page.

https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html